# How to prevent AnimatedWidgets in Flutter ListView from all moving together

Tags: listview, animation, flutter

I have a problem where I started adding leading icons to my listview tiles and then wanted to animate them.  I was able to follow the animation [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) enough to get them to start animating onTap, but they all animate together.  How do I make them unique?  I looked into passing a key to the AnimatedWidget constructor but that didn't seem to help.

Here is code that demonstrates my current problem.  If you tap, they all rotate 90 degrees and if you long press they animate back 90 degress

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _counter = 0;
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 285), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi/2).animate(controller);

  }


  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
            child: ListView(
              children: ListTile.divideTiles(
                context: context,
                tiles: [
                  ListTile(
                    leading: AnimatedChevron(animation: animation),
                    onTap: ()=> controller.forward(),
                    onLongPress: ()=> controller.reverse(),
                    title: Text('Sun'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: AnimatedChevron(animation: animation),
                    onTap: ()=> controller.forward(),
                    onLongPress: ()=> controller.reverse(),
                    title: Text('Moon'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: AnimatedChevron(animation: animation),
                    onTap: ()=> controller.forward(),
                    onLongPress: ()=> controller.reverse(),
                    title: Text('Star'),
                  ),
                ],
              ).toList(),
            ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedChevron extends AnimatedWidget {
  AnimatedChevron({Key key, Animation<double> animation})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> animation = listenable;
    return Transform.rotate(
        angle: animation.value,
        child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right, color: Colors.blue));
  }
}
```

[image]

Another [great tutorial on listview](https://pusher.com/tutorials/flutter-listviews) I used here.

Comment: You must have one animationController per item

Comment: Ok, I can try that.  But what if I build the list with a list builder?  How would I create a new animationController in the ListView.builder() ?

Comment: Ok, got this working by doing a Map of AnimationController's since I needed a way to refer to them by id (hence the Map).  Then I have to dispose of them by walking the Map at then end.  Seems a bit resource intensive, but maybe it's fine.  For my medium size list it worked very well.

Comment: Any performatic way to do this for big lists?